# Google Chrome is showing IMG only on smallest resolution (CSS @MEDIA)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap-3

there is an issue at my bootstrap-carousel using google chrome.
In my CSS i've defined serveral @media widths to show an image and text perfectly on each resolution. It works well in Edge, IE and Firefox. But Google Chrome is showing the IMG only at the smalles resolution (max 767px).

My "Resolution-settings":

```
@media (min-width: 1420px){
    .reference {
        display: flex;
        width: 1170px;
        padding-left: calc((100%-1179px)/2);
        padding-right: calc((100%-1179px)/2);
    }
    .reference-img {
        width: 50%;
    }
    .reference-info {
        padding-top: 70px;
        width: 50%;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        text-shadow: 0px 1px 4px #000000;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    .reference-info h1{
        font-size: 60px;
    }
    .reference-info h2{
        font-size: 40px;
    }
    .ctrl-style {
        font-size: 40px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1090px) and (max-width: 1419px){
    .reference {
        display: flex;
        width: 900px;
        padding-left: calc((100%-900px)/2);
        padding-right: calc((100%-900px)/2);
    }
    .reference-img {
        width: 50%;
    }
    .reference-info {
        padding-top: 50px;
        width: 50%;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        text-shadow: 0px 1px 4px #000000;
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    .reference-info h1{
        font-size: 50px;
    }
    .reference-info h2{
        font-size: 30px;
    }
    .ctrl-style {
        font-size: 40px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 880px) and (max-width: 1089px){
    .reference {
        display: flex;
        width: 700px;
        padding-left: calc((100%-700px)/2);
        padding-right: calc((100%-700px)/2);
    }
    .reference-img {
        width: 50%;
    }
    .reference-info {
        padding-top: 20px;
        width: 50%;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        text-shadow: 0px 1px 4px #000000;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    .reference-info h1{
        font-size: 35px;
        margin-bottom: 0px !important;
    }
    .reference-info h2{
        font-size: 30px;
        margin-bottom: 0px !important;
    }
    .ctrl-style {
        font-size: 40px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 879px){
    .reference {
        display: flex;
        width: 600px;
        padding-left: calc((100%-600px)/2);
        padding-right: calc((100%-600px)/2);
    }
    .reference-img {
        width: 50%;
    }
    .reference-info {
        padding-top: 15px;
        width: 50%;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        text-shadow: 0px 1px 4px #000000;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    .reference-info h1{
        font-size: 30px;
        margin-bottom: 0px !important;
    }
    .reference-info h2{
        font-size: 25px;
        margin-bottom: 0px !important;
    }
    .ctrl-style {
        font-size: 40px;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 767px){
    .reference {
        width: 100%;
        padding-left: 50px;
        padding-right: 50px;
    }
    .reference-img {
        width: 90%;
        padding-left: 5%;
        padding-right: 5%;
    }
    .reference-info {
        padding-top: 15px;
        width: 100%;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        text-shadow: 0px 1px 4px #000000;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    .reference-info h1{
        font-size: 22px;
        margin-bottom: 0px !important;
    }
    .reference-info h2{
        font-size: 22px;
        margin-bottom: 0px !important;
    }
    .ctrl-style {
        font-size: 25px;
    }
}
```

Here is a Bootply, open this with Chrome and you will be able to see what i mean.
http://www.bootply.com/tcUZLBKQna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have remove the padding `calc()` method now its working fine all browsers
try with snippet and change to full screen

```css
@media (min-width: 1420px){
 .reference {
  display: flex;
  width: 1170px;
 }
 .reference-img {
  width: 50%;
 }
 .reference-info {
  padding-top: 70px;
  width: 50%;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 4px #000000;
  font-size: 20px;
 }
 .reference-info h1{
  font-size: 60px;
 }
 .reference-info h2{
  font-size: 40px;
 }
 .ctrl-style {
  font-size: 40px;
 }
}
@media (min-width: 1090px) and (max-width: 1419px){
 .reference {
  display: flex;
  width: 900px;
 }
 .reference-img {
  width: 50%;
 }
 .reference-info {
  padding-top: 50px;
  width: 50%;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 4px #000000;
  font-size: 16px;
 }
 .reference-info h1{
  font-size: 50px;
 }
 .reference-info h2{
  font-size: 30px;
 }
 .ctrl-style {
  font-size: 40px;
 }
}
@media (min-width: 880px) and (max-width: 1089px){
 .reference {
  display: flex;
  width: 700px;
 }
 .reference-img {
  width: 50%;
 }
 .reference-info {
  padding-top: 20px;
  width: 50%;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 4px #000000;
  font-size: 14px;
 }
 .reference-info h1{
  font-size: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 0px !important;
 }
 .reference-info h2{
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 0px !important;
 }
 .ctrl-style {
  font-size: 40px;
 }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 879px){
 .reference {
  display: flex;
  width: 600px;
 }
 .reference-img {
  width: 50%;
 }
 .reference-info {
  padding-top: 15px;
  width: 50%;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 4px #000000;
  font-size: 14px;
 }
 .reference-info h1{
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 0px !important;
 }
 .reference-info h2{
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 0px !important;
 }
 .ctrl-style {
  font-size: 40px;
 }
}
@media (max-width: 767px){
 .reference {
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
 }
 .reference-img {
  width: 90%;
  padding-left: 5%;
  padding-right: 5%;
 }
 .reference-info {
  padding-top: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 4px #000000;
  font-size: 14px;
 }
 .reference-info h1{
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-bottom: 0px !important;
 }
 .reference-info h2{
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-bottom: 0px !important;
 }
 .ctrl-style {
  font-size: 25px;
 }
}

.ctrl-style {
 color: #FFFFFF;
 -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
 -moz-transition-duration: 0.2s;
 -o-transition-duration: 0.2s;
 transition-duration: 0.2s;
}
.ctrl-style:hover {
 color: #51B5B6 !important;
}
.ctrl-style:focus {
 color: #FFFFFF;
}
.carousel-control-left {
 top: 50%;
 position: absolute;
 left: 5%;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 text-align: center;
 text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
 outline: none;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.carousel-control-right {
 top: 50%;
 position: absolute;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 text-align: center;
 text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
 right: 5%;
 left: auto;
 outline: none;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.carousel-control-right:focus, .carousel-control-left:focus {
 outline: none;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.carousel-indicators {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row portfolio-padding">
   <center>
   <div id="referenceCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="8000">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
     <li data-target="#referenceCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
     <li data-target="#referenceCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
     <div class="item active">
      <div class="reference">
       <div class="reference-img">
        <img src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/images/Simplest-Responsive-jQuery-Image-Lightbox-Plugin-simple-lightbox.jpg" style="width: 100%">
       </div>
       <div class="reference-info">
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1><br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="item">
      <div class="reference">
       <div class="reference-img">
        <img src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/images/Simplest-Responsive-jQuery-Image-Lightbox-Plugin-simple-lightbox.jpg" style="width: 100%">
       </div>
       <div class="reference-info">
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1><br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-left ctrl-style" href="#referenceCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-right ctrl-style" href="#referenceCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
   </div>
  </center>
 </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I just wanted to write the same and answer my own question. I was searching for the issue and found it by my own. It seems like Chrome don't like calculating like (x+y)/a.. :) Tanks anyway :)